# wordpress upload function for plugin?

Tags: wordpress, function, plugins, upload

Is there any function in wordpress for fileupload? I need this for the plugin i'm writing but I'm guessing wordpress should have something for it. Otherwise I'll need to write it myself.
I've looked at the function list but couldn't find anything, so maybe I'm missing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look at the the [custom fields template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/) code and see what you can get

Comment: I ended up writing it myself. Thanks for the suggestion!